# Is there any way to play h264 video in a java applet?

Tags: java, video, applet, h.264

Is there any way to play h264 video in a Java applet? Not Java FX, but a plain old-school Java applet? I had a look at Xuggler but these guys do not support applets at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can play video in Java applet but that would require you to implement your own player.

To decode video you can use JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ), it has a handy class called FrameGrab, and you can use it like this:

```
int frameNumber = 10000;
FileChannelWrapper ch = null;
try {
    ch = NIOUtils.readableFileChannel(new File("path to file name"));
    FrameGrab frameGrab = new FrameGrab(ch);

    frameGrab.seek(frameNumber);
    BufferedImage frame;
    for (int i = 0; (frame = frameGrab.getFrame()) != null && i < 200; i++) {
        ImageIO.write(frame, "jpg", new File(String.format("img%08d.png", i)));
    }
} finally {
    NIOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
}
```

If you are also planning to play audio you can use: JAAD ( http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/ ) and do something like this:

```
Decoder dec = new Decoder(decoderSpecificinfo);
SampleBuffer buf = new SampleBuffer();
dec.decodeFrame(aacFrame, buf);
//the aacFrame array contains the AAC frame to decode
byte[] audio = buf.getData(); //this array contains the raw PCM audio data
```